# wordpress - how to get php variable in page from sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote my own custom page template for my Wordpress page, now I want to change sidebar.php to insert a small menu whenever that page template is loaded.

```
// sidebar.php
if ( isset($event_name) ) {
  // do something
}
```

But apparently sidebar.php doesn't recognize variable $event_name.

How do I come about solving this?

Comment: Where does `$event_name` come from? Where do you define it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with the way WordPress implements templates, have you tried declaring the variable `global` in the sidebar page?

Comment: This is correct. I'm assuming you're using get_sidebar to retrieve your sidebar. The scope is different inside of get_sidebar then in your page template so you need to globalize your variable.

Comment: I saw they used a function to get the sidebar and guessed the rest. So the master template is really just in the global namespace?

Comment: I totally forget about globalize the variable. besides I combine this with is_page_template and it works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

See: [Function Reference/is page template « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) to be able to detect page template in use.